# Firestore Rules: get() throws Error instead of returning null when document does not exist (only in Prod & Emulator; works with the rule tester)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my security rules, I make a `get()` for a `userDoc`.

If the doc does not exists, the `get()` should return `null` (cf [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get)), and the rule should allow the request *(if the doc exists, then the rule should allow only if the doc has the right `version` field)*

**The issue is: the rules reject the creation of the first document when on prod (= when the userDoc does not exists), but they work when I test them with the test tool**

I reproduce the same error with the emulator, so I've been able to use the rule checker, and I observe that the `get()` throws an error instead of returning a `null` value (despite having a correctly formed argument). *This is coherent with the fact that in prod I do not have `denied request` but only `error request` in the console.*

[image: Security Rules analyzer screenshot]

The complete function is as follow:

```
        function resourceVersionIsCompatible(resourceVersion) {
          let userDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId));
          let serverVersion = userDoc != null && 'version' in userDoc.data ? int(string(userDoc.data.version).split('\\.')[0]) : 0;
          return (serverVersion == 0) || (resourceVersion == serverVersion);          
        }
```

If I replace `userDoc != null` by `false`, then it works well (I can create the first document, which initialize the userDoc thanks to a Cloud Function. And then I can restore the normal rules to successfully create the subsequent documents with working version check).

The complete rules are below:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

        // Everything is disallowed if not specifically allowed after
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /users/{userId} {

      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow write: if false;

      match /{collection}/{documentId} {

        function resourceIsValid(resourceVersion) {
          return resourceVersion <= 2 && {
            'version-1': (collection == 'interactions' || collection == 'contacts'),
            'version-2': (collection == 'events' || collection == 'contacts')
          }['version-' + string(resourceVersion)];
        }

        function resourceVersionIsCompatible(resourceVersion) {
          let userDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId));
          let serverVersion = userDoc != null && 'version' in userDoc.data ? int(string(userDoc.data.version).split('\\.')[0]) : 0;
          // We allow the request if the resourceVersion is the same major than the serverVersion
          // of if there is no serverVersion (then a cloud function will initiate it based on the doc version)
          return (serverVersion == 0) || (resourceVersion == serverVersion);          
        }

        function creationAllowed() {
            let resourceVersionMajor = 'v' in request.resource.data ? int(string(request.resource.data.v).split('\\.')[0]) : 1;
          return request.auth.uid == userId
            && resourceIsValid(resourceVersionMajor)
            && resourceVersionIsCompatible(resourceVersionMajor);
        }

        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow create, update: if creationAllowed();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a bug report, file it with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: It could be a bug, but I could also be doing something wrong. Anyway, I opened a ticket.

Comment: If you think you might be doing something wrong, reduce the rules accompanying query down to the simplest, most minimal code that you can that still doesn't work the way you expect. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The only thing that could cause this is if either `$(database)` or `$(userId)` (which is more likely) does not have the expected value for some reason, I would say that you should log this value somehow out of the firebase rules to check if it is what is expected. If it is, I agree you should either contact firebase support or open a bug report on google's [issue tracker system](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, they do have the value they should have, and the request still fails. But technically, since they are pointing to a non existing document, their value is not really important: the problem is that the get() returns an error when the doc does not exist instead of a null value. So I suppose it's a Firestore issue then.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, simply getting a document that doesn't exists and checking doc == null causes an error even though the Firebase docs say that get should return a null if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a get to a document that doesn't exist, it can cause an entire expression to fail.

if you have

```
allow read: if false || true;
```

this will evaluate to true. But if you have:

```
allow read: if get(document_that_does_not_exist) || true;
```

then the get does not evaluate to false, it fails. So the read will not be allowed.

You can use `exists` to verify a document exists before using get. But using get in this way can be a handy shortcut to force something to fail if the document indeed, does not exist but you want to use the data if it does.